# Magento module routing old urls to controller/action

Tags: magento, routes

I created a SOAP server outside of Magento (lets call it www.example.com/soap/). The directory `/soap` looks like this:

```
example.wsdl
example_server.php
```

There are helper classes that I'm ignoring because the users don't see those. What I want to do is move this code into a Magento module and use the router to avoid forcing users to change their URLs. Is this possible? For example, when a user requests www.example.com/soap/example.wsdl I want to route that to `My_Newsoap_IndexController::wsdlAction()`.

This is what I've got in my config.xml right now:

```
<frontend>
  <routers>
    <newsoap>
      <use>standard</use>
      <args>
        <module>My_Newsoap</module>
        <frontName>soap</frontName>
      </args>
    </newsoap>
  </routers>
</frontend>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conditional yes, but not the way you're thinking.  The `<routers/>` tags in the Magento config setup a very specific sort of routing.  In plain english, you can say

"URLs that start with this `<frontName/>` should be handled by this module"

Outside of that though, there's no further way to setup custom routes by configuration alone.

What you can do is configure a custom **router** object, and then write PHP code to implement your routing logic however you want to.  The how of this goes beyond a simple Stack Overflow answer, but you can get the full story in [this series of articles](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#dispatch), or see an example of custom routing in [the simple page](http://alanstorm.com/magento_simple_page_django) module, (self links).